# What this error means and how to solve it?

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, android-ndk, android-stlport

I am trying to build a C++ code using NDK in android. I have a method which has a parameter             `vector < vector <float> > coordinates`

Everything builds fine until I write this line inside my method

`vector<float> firstPoint = coordinates.at(0);`

I start getting this error

```
D:/eclipseworkspace/myLibProject/obj/local/armeabi/libmyLibProject.a(FileName.o): In function `std::priv::_Vector_base<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::allocator<std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > > >::_M_throw_out_of_range() const':
D:/androidndk/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.c:45: undefined reference to `std::__stl_throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/cygdrive/d/eclipseworkspace/myLibProject/obj/local/armeabi/libOutputName.so] Error 1
```

I have no clue why this is happening and Google is not helping either.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any element at index 0? Looks like coordinates is empty.

Comment: As I said coordinate is parameter to this method and this is compile time error not runtime. And yes at runtime coordinates will eventually have at least one value

Comment: How are you compiling and linking your code? Is it possible you are missing the standard libraries?

Comment: If compiler is unable to find libs then Why the error comes when I try to access value and not when I have declared it in the method parameters?

Comment: Because **most** of the implementation of vector is in header files, and so doesn't need a library. It seems in your case everything is in header files except the exception class thrown by vector::at. This seems perfectly normal. (One confusing aspect of STLPort is that you see a reference to _vector.c, but if you check the STLPort code you'll see that _vector.c is included in the vector header file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed

```
vector<float> firstPoint = coordinates.at(0);
```

to

```
vector<float> firstPoint = coordinates[0];
```

it started compiling..... :s y?

Answer (score 1):

This is a linking error. You need to add `APP_STL := stlport_static` to your `Apllication.mk` file. Also make sure that you use `-fno-exceptions` flag, since STLport is not compatible with C++ exceptions and RTTI.

You can get more info in [`APPLICATION-MK.HTML`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#docs) which is availavle in the `docs` folder of the NDK. `CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.HTML` is also worth to read.

Comment: Make sure that you use `-fno-exceptions` flag. STLport is not compatible with C++ exceptions and RTTI.

Comment: @Haris Hasan, That's because coordinates[0] should not throw exceptions, it doesn't check bounds. You need to compile your project with `-fno-exceptions` flag.

Comment: I did but even then I am getting same error unless I use `[]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using two different implementation of the standard library in the same project.

It looks like you are compiling your files with (the headers of) an stlport implementation of the standard library in D:/android..., and you link against your local library.

You have to configure the linker in your ide (or Makefile) to use also the lib file of the same implementation (somewhere in D:/android... I guess).

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a linker error. You probably forgot to add STL library reference to  your build. Or it can't be found

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this ?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```